# Angular deep link refresh fails while app is hosted

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I I am working on Angular 7. I have problem with deep link(www.example.com/deeplink) while my app is hosted if i do refresh. Precisely , it works perfect while on development. but after hosting, if i refresh page will not be available.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use hash Location Strategy .Just use it on app module.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure a rewrite on your server. Check the docs here.
https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Server side
Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html)

The reason for this is that when you first visit the page (/deeplink), e.g. after a refresh, the browser has no way of knowing that this isn't a real URL, so it goes ahead and loads it. However if you have loaded up the root page first, and all the javascript code, then when you navigate to /deeplink Angular can get in there before the browser tries to hit the server and handle it accordingly.

If you have .htaccess you can:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: This is not necessary to change on .htaccess . you just have to use  hash Location Strategy on angular routing.